# Repeated Failure before success, in app purchases

Tags: objective-c, xcode, in-app-purchase, exc-bad-access, ios5

Ive set up in app purchases. Everything works correctly except randomly after a couple purchases i get EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the addPayment: line. This i believe is some sort of memory issues that im having a heck of a time trying to figure out. On inspecting things i noticed another peculiar behavior. In SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed i put an NSLog, This log triggers ~50 times before the alert view for the in app purchase pops up, then it stops and i can continue normally with my purchase. Is this normal? Could this be the reason im getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS? Im using xcode 4 preview 6 and programming for iOS5.

Comment: Could it be that you're adding same transaction observer more than once (i.e. for each `addPayment:` statement)?

Comment: I dont think so. There is only one addPayment: which occurs directly after addTransactionObserver:

Comment: Still though, this should not be the case. Apple recommends adding transaction observer ASAP during application startup.

Comment: how would i go about doing that? All the in app purchase stuff is in its own class. So would i create an instance of the that in the mainView viewDidLoad and add it as transaction observer? i.e. myPurchaseClass *transactionObserver = [[myPurchaseClass alloc] init]; [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:myPurchaseClass];
If not that then how

Comment: I'd suggest adding app delegate as transaction observer, implement delegate methods there and call appropriate (custom made) notifications from there, that your purchase view controller class could listen to.

Comment: Im getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS right off the bat doing that. would it be:
appDelegate *observer = [[appDelegate alloc] init];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:observer];
or am i doing something wrong? this is in the mainView viewDidLoad

Comment: Check this: https://gist.github.com/8c0b5c3a8cd93204bb15

Comment: thanks! adding transaction observer to the app delegate fixed everything!